# Configuration challenge with ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, linux

I tried to configure ElasticBeanstalk and got the output below:

Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions', OptionName: 'ManagedActionsEnabled'): You can't enable managed platform updates when your environment uses the service-linked role 'AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalk'. Select a service role that has the 'AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy' managed policy.

Comment: This kind of problem is difficult for posters to diagnose since we can't see your code. What have you tried following the error message? It sounds like the error message can give you some guidance about what is going wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.